# Add normal curve to categorical data in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some exemplary data:

```
exampleData = data.frame(UniqueID= c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E","F","G"),
                         value = c(5,20,40,70,11,8,1))
```

that I plot in ggplot2 using:

```
ggplot(data=exampleData, aes(x=UniqueID, y=value )) + 
       geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image]

What I would like to do now is to add a normal curve for this categorical Data assuming that the graph is symmetrical, that is: C=E=51/2 B=F=28/2 A=G=6/2

In general I didn't find any good reference for adding lines for categorical data - every solution I found refers to histograms or situations when the values on x axis are numeric, but is there any method to add lines for categorical data (most preferably a normal curve)?

Comment: Have you searched at all? I find 66 hits for an SO search on terms: `[r] histogram normal curve`. Surely one of answers uses ggplt2 functions. (And probably some of them use "barplots" which is what you would use for categorical data, ... not histograms which are used for continuous data.)

Comment: Yes, I did try searching it for quite some time - but i wasn't able to find the way to add a normal curve to a barplot. Maybe some modifications to the already existing solutions (using histograms) would work but I wasn't able to figure it out yet, that's why I asked for help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37387043/how-to-superimpose-a-line-graph-on-a-barplot-in-ggplot2

Comment: Guess I shouldn't add the part with adding lines to cathegorical data in ggplot as that indeed is pretty simple. The main problem is creating a normal curve having only 7 values on x axis and corresponding values on y axis. Normally, in histograms the values are numeric and the inbuild function in ggplot2 does is somehow. What I struggle with is finding a way to mimic it's work to my example :/

Comment: What are you really trying to do and why? Where did you get the idea this was a good thing to do with categorical data?